how to fix Connection could not be established with host error?

local.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host "ssl://awamir.one:465": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://awamir.one:465 (Connection refused) {"userId":134,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException(code: 0): Connection could not be established with host "ssl://awamir.one:465": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://awamir.one:465 (Connection refused) at /var/www/awamir/vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Smtp/Stream/SocketStream.php:154)


I think Connection refused may be a clue. Did you pass a userid and password

Are you sure awamir.one:465 is the correct host/port? That host doesn't seem to have that port open.

yes, i use right pass a userid and password
